# Datacard is not detecting in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Whenever i'm trying to connect any type of datacard like photon plus/airtel 3G  its not detecting. I'm using ubuntu 12.04 version.I've tried a lot i.e,
Wired connections->Mobile Broadband->add->new mobile broadband connection->select country->select type(airtel/docomo)->continue->apply. But i'm not able to connecting, even its not detecting at my laptop... pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following command to see if you your datacard is getting detected or not.

```
lsusb
```

It may provide details similar to this:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:8126 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp.
```